# VideoPlayer in Xamarin forms start in fullscreen?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is it possible to start the VideoPlayer in fullscreen?

When opening a page, like the PlayWebVideoPage in the demo, would it be possible to start the VideoPlayer in fullscreeen instead of windowed?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. I have downvoted your question, because your question doesn't comply with the guidelines. Above all you should check [**How to ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve that, your video page must be set without NavigationBar:

`NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);`

And then, you will also have to hide the Status Bar, both in Android and iOS.